# How to use junit to test db query in vert.x

Tags: java, vert.x

I want to test the code of query database.
I reading the [doc](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-junit5/java/),and write such code.

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMainVerticle {
  Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
  @Test
  public void test(TestContext testContext)throws Exception{
    var config =  MainVerticle.getDbConfig();
    JDBCPool pool = JDBCPool.pool(vertx, config);
    System.out.println("a");  // print a
    pool.query("select 1 from test").execute(event -> {
      System.out.println("b");  // not execute to here
    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

But when i run it  ,it just print the
**a** in the consule ,it seems not run to the pont **b**

### My question is

How to test Db query in `vert.x` with `junit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a DB connectivity which cannot be reported within the 1 second sleep time.

Anyway, when testing asynchronous code, you must use the `TestContext` to make sure the test is not finished too early:

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMainVerticle {
  Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
  @Test
  public void test(TestContext testContext)throws Exception{
    var config =  MainVerticle.getDbConfig();
    JDBCPool pool = JDBCPool.pool(vertx, config);
    System.out.println("a");  // print a
    pool.query("select 1 from test").execute(testContext.succeeding(event -> {
      System.out.println("b");
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: i try to it later

Comment: from `testContext.succeeding` to  ` testContext.asyncAssertSuccess`  , it work for me ,i found the real problem is `No suitable driver`